# Scoping a click method for an angular application

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular application where I am showing some menu bar upon clicking on an icon. I am using a scope variable and using ng-show to show/hide the same. It works fine, but there is a new requirement which states that if someone clicks on any other part of the application the menu should close. Now the problem is that when I am using an ng-click in the body it is triggering both the scope methods, i.e. for the icon click as well as the body click, since the icon is also within the body. What approach should I take for this? Do I need a different controller for the same?

Answer (score 0):

on the click event you need to make sure the target is not the icon (consider also excluding the menu itself).

something like this:

```
$document.on('click', function (event) {
                if (event.pageX == 0 && event.pageY == 0) return;

                var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
                if (!(elm.contains(target))) {
                    // close the menu
                }
            });
```

elm is your icon element

also, consider using a directive such as: https://github.com/IamAdamJowett/angular-click-outside

Comment: The problem here is that when the event is triggered from the body it should only close the menu if it is opened. If it is triggered from the icon then the menu should open if closed and close if open. Now taking a cue from your answer if I write the logic as:                                                            if (!(elm.contains(target))) {
             // open the menu if close and vice versa
                }else { close the menu if open}. This event is getting triggered twice hence first the menu is appearing and then closing off. I am currently using ng-click and not a directive.

Comment: I recommend checking out the directive i linked to. It provides the functionality you need: click will close the menu and you can exclude elements

Answer (score 0):

In the close listener added to the body, check that the event doesn't come from your the icon:

```
var closeListener = function(event) {
    if (!iconElement.contains(event.target)) {
        closeMenu();
    }
};
```

Comment: The problem is that the click even is being triggered twice. Once for the parent container and another time for the child. As a result the menu is opening and then closing off.